# can't sort data in Postgresql data type json

Tags: php, sql, json, postgresql

I'm currently trying out the "new" data type json.
This is part of the definition as php Array (one row of data that is stored in the field)

```
'processed'=>array(5):
        ["ct"]=>
        int(1)
        ["wt"]=>
        int(11)
        ["cpu"]=>
        int(0)
        ["mu"]=>
        int(1056)
        ["pmu"]=>
        int(0)
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT id, data->>'processed'>'ct' as sortField FROM system_debug ORDER BY sortField ASC
```

but all I get in return is an table like this:

```
id  sortfield
    6   true
    7   true
    8   true
    9   true
    10   true
    11   true
    12   true
    13   true
    14   true
    15   true
    16   true
    17   true
    18   true
```

I'm trying to implement Sorting without the needs of storing the data seperatly inside the table.
Where am I mistaking?

Table Scheme:

```
                CREATE TABLE system_debug (
                    data JSON,
                    id integer NOT NULL
                );

                CREATE SEQUENCE system_debug_id_seq
                START WITH 1
                INCREMENT BY 1
                NO MINVALUE
                NO MAXVALUE
                CACHE 1;

                ALTER SEQUENCE system_debug_id_seq OWNED BY system_debug.id;

                ALTER TABLE ONLY system_debug ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval(\'system_debug_id_seq\'::regclass);
```

I appreceate any help that I can get ^^

Comment: Probably a typo: `SELECT id, data->>'processed'->'ct'`

Comment: Hmmm that didn't work.

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown
LINE 1: SELECT id, data->>'processed'->'ct' FROM system_debug;
                                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: `SELECT id, data->'processed'->'ct'` two typos, sorry ;)

Comment: Klin can you post your reply as an answer, so I can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
data->>'processed'>'ct'
```

is of type boolean as `>` is `greater than` operator. You probably wanted to get

```
SELECT id, data->'processed'->'ct' ...
```